# GCP data catalog/dataflex - can I register Kafka topics and on-prem databases?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-data-catalog, google-dataplex

Is it possible to also register/add metadata of **Kafka topics/producers/consumers** and on-premise databases etc in GCP data catalog/Dataplex?

Could someone please point me to some examples how to do the same?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it help? https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/integrate-data-sources#integrate_on-premises_data_sources

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks for the link. Yes was going through that document and thought to check if someone has working examples to do that. But after reading the documents and few more articles, now I think I understood how to achieve that. Thanks for your time